# Как отправлять записи на стену в группе в Контакте с сервера по крону?

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

В идеале нужно следующее: есть на сервере папка с изображениями, раз в сутки в определенную группу нужно отправлять одно изображение. Проблема возникает именно с отправкой сообщения на стену с помощью wall.post, а еще точнее с авторизацией.

Как я понимаю, для отправки нужно использовать что-то вроде такого:

```
$request_params = array(
    'owner_id' => $group_id,
    'from_group' => '1',
    'message' => 'Some text.',
    'access_token' => $access_token,
    'v' => '5.52'
    );
$get_params = http_build_query($request_params);
$result = json_decode(file_get_contents('https://api.vk.com/method/wall.post?'. $get_params));
```

Ответ либо 7(Нет прав для выполнения этого действия.) либо 17(Требуется валидация пользователя.)

Как я понимаю, ошибка именно в access_token. Его нужно получать для standalone приложения? Его нужно получить один раз или каждый раз перед отправкой на стену?
Техподдержка контакта отвечает весьма туманно. Есть рабочий пример?

Comment: PHP - не standalone приложение... поэтому ничего у вас не выйдет.

Comment: Для Standalone -- да, нужен Access Token (по крайней мере для ваших действий). Выше написали что у вас не Standalone, однако в контексте вашей задачи я не понимаю почему нельзя сделать Standalone-приложение в виде какого-нибудь скрипта, который будет периодически запускаться на сервере и выполнять нужные вам действия. Также отмечу что согласно https://new.vk.com/dev/wall.post и https://new.vk.com/dev/permissions действия со стеной доступны и для не-Standalone приложений.

Comment: @hunter для запуска что-то на сервере придется писать обходной путь, который что-то запусти, который где-то триггернет, который обратится к скрипту, который что-то сделает...... если это не проблема, а также есть знания другого языка, на котором сделано стандалоне - то проблем конечно не будет))......... для не standalone приложений возможна отправка на стену только с помощью окна подтверждения.... так что вряд ли этот вариант подойдет

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, согласен.

Comment: Мне все-равно каким образом это будет работать, главное, что php-скрипт с сервера мог писать на стену. Что для этого нужно сделать?